# Encryption/decryption between Java and Android

Tags: java, android, security, aes

I am using the same code on Java SE and Android project. The apps running in Java and Android connect to the same MQTT broker and exchange messages. The messages are encrypted/decrypted using AES. I have very little experience with Java Security Architecture, so my questions are:

1) What should I expect if I use the same Cipher algorithm, but from different providers (one on Java and another on Android)? Does using a different provider to decrypt a message encrypted with another provider automatically mean that the message won't be decrypted successfully?

2) What would be a recommended provider to use that would allow Java and Android applications to communicate correctly in this case? I have seen some answers online, but some are relatively old, so I'm not sure if they are still best answers.

Comment: AES is a standard. Assuming you are using the same secret it should not matter whose implementation you are using

Comment: There are of course differences between the providers when the algorithm is not fully specified. Don't forget to specify the mode of operation and the padding. Don't use `Cipher.getInstance("AES");`, but rather `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");` or even better authenticated encryption such as GCM or CCM which is provided by BouncyCastle.

Comment: Use `BouncyCastle` on Java SE and `SpongyCastle` on Android. Same version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should I expect if I use the same Cipher algorithm, but from different providers (one on Java and another on Android)?

The same result.

> Does using a different provider to decrypt a message encrypted with another provider automatically mean that the message won't be decrypted successfully?

No.

> 2) What would be a recommended provider to use that would allow Java and Android applications to communicate correctly in this case?

The one built into the JRE, assuming it supports AES.

But I'm wondering why you aren't using SSL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Enabling SSL is in the pipeline. In terms of the provider used, would you then recommend that I don't specify a provider name  in the code, but to let the code use a default provider? Would that work 100% of the time?

Comment: If it works at all on both ends it should work 100% of the time. That doesn't absolve you from having to test it yourself. You'd be better off jumping straight to SSL. No point in building two incompatible versions of the product, one with dubious security.